# Javascript deriving a Tree from a set of URLs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Guys am trying to create a dynamic menu list. There is no limit to the depth of elements that can be created by a user.

## MY PROBLEM

My set of URL looks like this

```
var json_data = [
    {
        "title" : "Food",
        "path" : "/root",
    },
    {
        "title" : "Cloths",
        "path" : "/root",
    },
    {
        "title" : "Veg",
        "path" : "/root/Food",
    },
    {
        "title" : "Brinjal",
        "path" : "/root/Food/Veg",
    },
    {
        "title" : "T shirt",
        "path" : "/root/Cloths",
    },
    {
        "title" : "Shirt",
        "path" : "/root/Cloths",
    },
    {
        "title" : "Green brinjal",
        "path" : "/root/Food/Veg/Brinjal",
    }
];
```

I want the `titles` to be in a hierarchy format which I eventually will render in form of `ul > li` to create the menu - in front-end.

The Hierarchy should be something like this:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Food",
    "path": "/root",
    "children": [
      {
        "title": "Veg",
        "path": "/root/Food",
        "children": [
          {
            "title": "Brinjal",
            "path": "/root/Food/Veg",
            "children": [
              {
                "title": "Green brinjal",
                "path": "/root/Food/Veg/Brinjal",
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Cloths",
    "path": "/root",
    "children": [
      {
        "title": "T shirt",
        "path": "/root/Cloths",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "title": "Shirt",
        "path": "/root/Cloths",
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

## WHAT I TRIED

```
    // Add an item node in the tree, at the right position
    function addToTree( node, treeNodes ) {
        // Check if the item node should inserted in a subnode
        for ( var i=0; i<treeNodes.length; i++ ) {
            var treeNode = treeNodes[i];
            // "/store/travel".indexOf( '/store/' )
            if ( node.path.indexOf( treeNode.path + '/' ) == 0 ) {
                addToTree( node, treeNode.children );
                // Item node was added, we can quit
                return;
            }
        }
        // Item node was not added to a subnode, so it's a sibling of these treeNodes
        treeNodes.push({
            title: node.title,
            path: node.path,
            children: []
        });
    }
    //Create the item tree starting from menuItems
    function createTree( nodes ){
        var tree = [];

        for ( var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++ ) {
            var node = nodes[i];
            addToTree( node, tree );
        }
        return tree;
    }

// variable = "json_data" is the set of URLS
var menuItemsTree = createTree( json_data );
console.log(menuItemsTree)
```

And the result it yields is this:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Food",
    "path": "/root",
    "children": [
      {
        "title": "Veg",
        "path": "/root/Food",
        "children": [
          {
            "title": "Brinjal",
            "path": "/root/Food/Veg",
            "children": [
              {
                "title": "Green brinjal",
                "path": "/root/Food/Veg/Brinjal",
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "title": "T shirt",
        "path": "/root/Cloths",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "title": "Shirt",
        "path": "/root/Cloths",
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Cloths",
    "path": "/root",
    "children": []
  }
]
```

The elements `"T Shirt"` and `"Shirt"` is pushed inside the **Food's children:[]** which those should be inside **Cloth's children:[]**

The solution I have used is taken from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133657/create-a-nested-ul-menu-based-on-the-url-path-structure-of-menu-items)

I trying to derive an algorithm myself- but its not clicked exactly right yet. Please help if any one already has a solution. In case if I can derive a solution myself, I will share it here.
above code is
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is the logic. here is a **[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/mabw84o0/)**

```js
var json_data = [{
  "title": "Food",
  "path": "/root",
}, {
  "title": "Cloths",
  "path": "/root",
}, {
  "title": "Veg",
  "path": "/root/Food",
}, {
  "title": "Brinjal",
  "path": "/root/Food/Veg",
}, {
  "title": "T shirt",
  "path": "/root/Cloths",
}, {
  "title": "Shirt",
  "path": "/root/Cloths",
}, {
  "title": "Green brinjal",
  "path": "/root/Food/Veg/Brinjal",
},{
  "title": "Test cloth",
  "path": "/root/Cloths/Shirt",
}];


// Add an item node in the tree, at the right position
function addToTree(node, treeNodes) {
  var parentNode = GetTheParentNodeChildArray(node.path, treeNodes) || treeNodes;

  parentNode.push({
    title: node.title,
    path: node.path,
    children: []
  });
}

function GetTheParentNodeChildArray(path, treeNodes) {
  for (var i = 0; i < treeNodes.length; i++) {
    var treeNode = treeNodes[i];

    if (path === (treeNode.path + '/' + treeNode.title)) {
      return treeNode.children;
    } 
    else if (treeNode.children.length > 0) {
      var possibleParent = false;

      treeNode.children.forEach(function(item) {
        if (path.indexOf(item.path + '/' + item.title) == 0) {
          possibleParent = true;
          return false;
        }
      });

      if (possibleParent) {
        return GetTheParentNodeChildArray(path, treeNode.children)
      }
    }
  }
}


//Create the item tree starting from menuItems
function createTree(nodes) {
  var tree = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    var node = nodes[i];
    addToTree(node, tree);
  }
  return tree;
}

// variable = "json_data" is the set of URLS
var menuItemsTree = createTree(json_data);
console.log(menuItemsTree);
```

**Limitation of this logic:** This logic works if the parent node is parsed before the child nodes, hence it is recommended to sort the list of 
URLs ( i.e. `json_data[]` ) likewise.  Here's a snippet of [Sorting-before + tree-structuring-the-sorted](https://jsfiddle.net/Austin4Silvers/10kLsxhz/6/)

Hope this is helpful

Comment: Am sorry but with your solution the "Cloth" itself is going inside the "Food" and "Veg" is becoming "Food's" sibling

Comment: @SiddharthaChowdhury Oh I am sorry. I didnt test.. I will get back to you..

Comment: Sure Reddy please

Comment: @SiddharthaChowdhury I am working on it... :) the logic is getting tougher as you have mentioned the level might get any level deep... right now this is where I am https://jsfiddle.net/10kLsxhz/2/

Comment: Oh nice bro thanks putting so much effort. I am trying the same :)

Comment: Thank you so much @Reddy for your effort your answer helped. In the above fiddle (in comment) - Shirt and T-Shirt is not an element of Cloth's children[ ] array. Thanks

Comment: @SiddarthaChowdhury ya that was a logic incomplete. I just gave you that saying I was working on it.. And glad I could help you.. The question was interesting too