# JS creating tree from set of URL's

Tags: javascript, data-structures, tree

I have some difficulties in creating a tree from given array of URLs.
The main goal is to split the urls into segments and arrange them into parent-child.
For example given the array:

```js
   const data =  [
        {
            'id': '1',
            'name': '/home',
        },
        {
            'id': '2',
            'name': '/story',
        },
        {
            'id': '3',
            'name': '/story/summer-story',
        },
        {
            'id': '4',
            'name': '/story/summer-story/2019',
        },
    ]
```

The output should be:

```js
const tree = [
    {
        'id': '1',
        'name' : '/home',
        children: []
    },
    {
        'id': '2',
        'name': '/story',
        'children': [
            {
                'id' : '3',
                'name': '/story/summer-story',
                'children': [
                    {
                        'id': '4',
                        'name': '/story/summer-story/2019'
                    }
                ]
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

I have already have create some kind of solution using example from [Javascript deriving a Tree from a set of URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40945925/javascript-deriving-a-tree-from-a-set-of-urls)

The current solution I have works fine when there is url with one or two segments.Once it has more than two segments it adds the node on the root level instead of nesting into the falling parent node.

**Example code**

```js
export const addToTree = (node, treeNodes) => {
    const parentNode = getTheParentNodeChildArray(node.name, treeNodes) || treeNodes;

    parentNode.push({
        title: node.title,
        name: node.name,
        children: []
    });
};

export const getTheParentNodeChildArray = (path, treeNodes) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < treeNodes.length; i++) {
        const treeNode = treeNodes[i];

        const lastSegment = getStringWithoutLastSegment(path);
        const lastNode = getStringWithoutLastSegment(treeNode.name);

        if (lastNode === lastSegment) {
            return treeNode.children;
        }
        else if (treeNode.children.length > 0) {
            let possibleParent = false;

            treeNode.children.forEach(function(item) {
                const lastSegmentPath = getStringWithoutLastSegment(path);
                const lastSegmentItem = getStringWithoutLastSegment(item.name);

                if (lastSegmentItem === lastSegmentPath) {
                    possibleParent = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });

            if (possibleParent) {
                return getTheParentNodeChildArray(path, treeNode.children);
            }
        }
    }
};

export const createTree = (nodes) => {
    const tree = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        const node = nodes[i];
        addToTree(node, tree);
    }
    return tree;
};

export const getStringWithoutLastSegment = (str) => {
    const stringArray = str.split('/');
    stringArray.pop();
    return (stringArray.join('/'));
};
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I noticed an inconsistency: your 1 node has an empty `children` array, but your 4 node has no such `children` array. Is this intentional? If so, what logic should be used to build the result? Thanks!

Comment: Its just inconsistent! It should have just empty children array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done pretty directly in one function. The approach involves iterating over all of the nodes to be added, then traversing the tree directory by directory, creating nodes as appropriate. The final result isn't quite a tree since there are multiple roots, but it's helpful to have a dummy root in constructing it.

```js
const makeTree = data => {
  const base = {children: []};
  
  for (const node of data) {
    const path = node.name.match(/\/[^\/]+/g);
    let curr = base;
    
    path.forEach((e, i) => {
      const currPath = path.slice(0, i + 1).join("");
      const child = curr.children.find(e => e.name === currPath);
      
      if (child) {
        curr = child;
      }
      else {
        curr.children.push({
          id: node.id, name: currPath, children: []
        });
        curr = curr.children[curr.children.length-1];
      }
    });
  }
  
  return base.children;
};

const data = [
  {
    'id': '1',
    'name': '/home',
  },
  {
    'id': '2',
    'name': '/story',
  },
  {
    'id': '3',
    'name': '/story/summer-story',
  },
  {
    'id': '4',
    'name': '/story/summer-story/2019',
  },
];

console.log(makeTree(data));
```

Comment: The only thing I noticed is that the parent node must be before the child node in the base array otherwise the results become distorted. I guess the base array always must be sorted correctly.

Comment: I believe I fixed that shortly after you accepted the answer, so you may have used the buggy original version. The fix was `curr = curr.children[curr.children.length-1];`. Does it work now, and if not, would you mind adding an input that fails as an edit to your post? Thanks!